# Order Arabic data by alphabet letters

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, arabic

How can I order data grabbed from MySQL by Arabic alphabet ?

**Note:** I use `utf8_general_ci` as collation in MySQL, and the encoding is fine, I just want to know how to sort data by alphabet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to sort Arabic text in mysql database using php, you have to make sure that:

1. MySQL charset: `UTF-8 Unicode` (`utf8`)
2. MySQL connection collation: `utf8_general_ci`
3. Your database and table collations set to: `utf8_general_ci` or
   `utf8_unicode_ci`

So when your create your table set charset to utf8 :

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
name varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

If you have already a table encoded in `latin1`, convert it like this :

```
ALTER TABLE `my_table` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

See : [Character set in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/character-sets-table.html).

Then, you need to add a line in your PHP when you setup the database connection :

```
mysql_query ('SET NAMES \'UTF8\'');
```

Or :

```
mysql_set_charset ('UTF8'); // PHP 5.2.3 or greater.
```

Or if you're using `PDO`, you can pass it as a 4th parameter like this :

```
$db = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tests', 'root', '', 
               array (PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''));
```

Also don't forget to set the header of your pages to `utf8` :

```
header ('Content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Example sorting query :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM my_table ORDER BY name" ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. But when I used this solution the words decoded like this Ø§Ù„Ø´Ø±ÙˆÙ‚ and they didn't order by name. Any advice?